# How to get data in an array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

findParent() function returns the following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_item_id] => 3
            [order_id] => 2
            [product_id] => 77
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 268.00
        )

)
```

I want to get 2 in [order_id].

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
$childlessorder = findParent($order_id);
$order_id = $childlessorder['order_id'];
```

Can anyone tell me how to get data in an array?

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$order_id = $childlessorder[0]['order_id'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
$childlessorder = findParent($order_id);
$order_id = $childlessorder[0]['order_id'];
```

The function findParent() is returning a two dimensional array as is apparent from the two *Array* words in the dump. So to access any value from this array we need to use two indices. Think of this as a matrix with the element you're interested lying in xth row yth column. With x being 0 and y begin 'order_id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$childlessorder = findParent($order_id);
$order_id = $childlessorder[0]['order_id'];
```

?